# How do I put an icon in the title on an Angular-Strap tab?

Tags: angular-strap

I would like an angular-strap tab title to have an icon-font an then the text for the title.

The resulting html for the tab list would have to have an li that looks like the following.

```
<li class="ng-scope active" ng-class="$index == $panes.$active ? $activeClass : ''" ng-repeat="$pane in $panes">
    <a class="ng-binding" role="tab" ng-click="$setActive($index)" data-toggle="tab" ng-bind-html="$pane.title" data-index="0">
      <i ng-show="loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Home
    </a>
</li>
```

How do I express this in angular-strap?
It's very easy to do in strait bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use escaped html.

So, putting something like this in the title will display the icon

```
&lt;i ng-show=&quot;loading&quot; class=&quot;fa fa-spinner fa-spin&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt; Home
```